# Unknown CMake command "rospack"

Tags: cmake, rospack, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build old ROS package (originally made in 2009 by a third party). `make` returns this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (rospack):
Unknown CMake command "rospack".
```

1st 5 lines of CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

rospack(navgtn_common)
```

rospack runs from terminal with admin privilege.

`rosmake` seems also stuck at rospack in the same manner ([output](http://pastebin.com/rfQ0Snp3)).

Google  tells me that using `find_package` might be a solution ([reference](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Build_KDE4_Software)) but then I haven't figured out which package to call within that function.

Env: diamondback, Ubuntu 10.10

Any idea? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11051/unknown-cmake-command-%22rospack%22/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are looking for a ROS package, right?
Then have a look at the [rosbuild find_ros_package docs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists#rosbuild_find_ros_package).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-08-29**:
@dornhege thanks. Replacing "rospack" with "rosbuild_find_ros_package" has cleared the error. Didn't know CMake macros and command-line tools are different...